# Update Query Issues

Tags: mysql

Here is my update query.

```
    UPDATE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c, sugarcrm.qb_salesorders
    SET sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsleads_ida = sugarcrm.qb_salesorders.memo, sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = sugarcrm.qb_salesorders.id
    WHERE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders.id = sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb
```

When I run this it gives me Affected rows 0.

Here is my select statement using the same info that is in the WHERE statement.

```
    SELECT * from qb_salesorders_leads_c, sugarcrm.qb_salesorders 
    WHERE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = sugarcrm.qb_salesorders.id
```

This returns 354 Rows which is what I am expecting to update on the update query.  What am I missing.  Please help!

Comment: All of your queries are functional yet for some reason none of the data gets affected.

I now have figured out the issue.  It seems as though there are multiple records that have the same id numbers so mysql cannot update.  I am going to go back to the drawing board. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the implicit join to an explicit one:

```
UPDATE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c leads 
    INNER JOIN sugarcrm.qb_salesorders orders
    ON orders.id = leads.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb
SET leads.qb_salesorders_leadsleads_ida = orders.memo, 
    leads.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id
```

As you can see, I also used aliases to make the SQL compact and legible.

Comment: It is still returning Affected rows:0 during update but your join works fine when just doing a select statement.

Comment: Hmm.  This UPDATE is a little funny.  Two thoughts: (1) Ordinarily, you would have another WHERE condition to restrict the rows that are to be updated.  But here, we are updating every row in the join.  (2) "UPDATE returns the number of rows that were actually changed." See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html.  Change your data to force something to be updated and run the query again.

Comment: I am going to revise the question

Answer (score 0):

To UPDATE using a join, you have to use the explicit join syntax:

```
UPDATE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c
INNER JOIN sugarcrm.qb_salesorders
    ON qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb.id 
        = sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb
SET sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsleads_ida 
        = qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb.memo
    , sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb 
        = sugarcrm.qb_salesorders.id
```

Comment: I am going to revise the question