# MySQL Query being VERY Weird

Tags: mysql

There is some weird SQL going on. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c c
JOIN qb_salesorders orders ON c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id
SET c.qb_salesorders_leadsleads_ida = orders.memo
AND c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id
```

So when I run this I get 0 rows affected. Now if I replace the AND with a , then it comes back and says 354 rows affected.

Now you would think when I run the same exact query with the , it would give me the same result.  WRONG.  It comes back with 0 rows affected.

After that I can change the , to AND and it works again.

Did I discover a MySQL Bug or am I missing something here?

Comment: Continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10691679/update-query-issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you ran the syntactically correct query with the comma, it correctly affected 354 rows.  The reason it returns with 0 rows affected the second time is that the rows *were already updated* the first time you ran the query.

If the column values will not be changed by an `UPDATE` query, MySQL will not update the rows, and they won't be counted in the affected rows.  Only those whose values actually change are counted.

Comment: Thank you I just thought I was going crazy!

Answer (score 1):

AND is not valid syntax for what you're trying to do.  Use commas to separate each column you're trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

You are already joining on c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id. So if you're using the "AND c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id " to filter your results, this is both incorrect syntax and unnecessary, since that is taken care of in the JOIN clause.

If you want to set the field specified in the AND clause, the join will only update those rows where those values are already equal (based on your join). The only correction I see here is that you would need to just remove the "AND" clause, as it has no effect other than causing an error in the query itself:

```
 UPDATE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c c 
 JOIN qb_salesorders orders ON c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id 
 SET c.qb_salesorders_leadsleads_ida = orders.memo
```

Further to that, to update multiple fields, they should be separate by commas (not ANDs):

```
UPDATE sugarcrm.qb_salesorders_leads_c c 
JOIN qb_salesorders orders ON c.qb_salesorders_leadsqb_salesorders_idb = orders.id 
 SET c.qb_salesorders_leadsleads_ida = orders.memo, c.anotherfield = "new value"
```